# ElasticSearch- update if exists- else create

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I'm looking for a best practise in Elastic Search-
I need to update a document if it exists (by id) and if it doesn't- create it.
What is the best way performance wise? 
I'm using elasticsearch node module, and looking for a solution like-

```
POST /indexName/test/8/_update
{
   "doc" : {
      "tags" : [ "testing" ],
      "views": 5
   },
   "doc_as_upsert" : true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link if you are looking for a bulk upsert operation:
http://elasticsearchserverbook.com/elasticsearch-0-90-1-updates-in-bulk-api/